# Floating action button hides behing the footer

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am designing a page using `angular-material` and I want to add a chat button at the bottom right corner of the screen and this button should scroll as I scroll down the page just like this website: http://harleytherapy.com/

I have done most of the part i.e. button is there at the bottom right corner and it also scrolls with the page as I start scrolling the page but the only problem is that when I reach the bottom, that button goes behind the footer and become invisible. I want it to stay above the footer when I reach the bottom. 
Here is my code:

```
<div class="main-content-container">

    <button mat-fab class="chat-icon-btn">
        <mat-icon class="chat-icon">chat_bubble_outline</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <h1>Dashboard&nbsp;<mat-icon aria-label="false">dashboard</mat-icon>
    </h1>
    <!-- Some more content -->


    <footer class="footer">
        <span>
          <a href="#" class="footer-links">Hjem</a><span class="vertical-divider"></span>
          <a href="#" class="footer-links">Om </a> <span class="vertical-divider"></span>
          <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Hjælp </a> <span class="vertical-divider"></span>
          <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Kontakt os </a> <span class="vertical-divider"></span>
          <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Webstedsbetingelser </a> <span class="vertical-divider"></span>
          <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Fortrolighedspolitik</a>
        </span>
      </footer>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-content-container {
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.chat-icon-btn {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #3900B3;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.chat-icon {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #3900B3;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.footer-links {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: navajowhite;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide z-index to button so that it comes at top of footer.

```
.chat-icon-btn {
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: when I add z-index, the button becomes visible but comes over the footer. I want the button to stay at the top of the footer when the footer starts.

Comment: can i see the issue in the link specified by you? I did not understand your issue.

Comment: That link is just for reference. If you open that link and start scrolling, you will see a chat button at the bottom right corner.

Comment: You mean unless the user scroll down and reaches to bottom (footer), the button should not be visible.

Comment: No I mean, when user reaches to bottom where footer section starts, that button stays at the top of footer section. Right now, it goes inside the footer section.

Comment: not able to understand your issue, can you please add pictures before my solution and after my solution.

Comment: Actually I resolved it using z-index. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Nice, glad it helped you!